# Rerender a part of a web-page

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I'm using `JSP`. I have a form needed to submit on the `listUser.jsp` page:

```
<form class="emp-delete">
    <label for="emp-id">Id:</label>
    <input type="text" id="emp-id" />
    <input type="submit" value="delete" />
    <c:out value="${message}" />
</form>
```

Form submition executes a business logic on the server and adds `message` parameter to the model as follows:

```
@RequestMappin(value="mapping")
public String deleteUser(Model m){
    String msg = null;
    // execute some logic
    m.addAttribute("message", msg);
    return "listUser";
}
```

The thing is such a method rerender the web-page entirely, but I need to just refresh value of the `<c:out>` tag. How can I do that?

Comment: Using JSP alone, no way. Use the XMLHttpRequest facilities of JavaScript (AJAX). More concretely, you could post the form using AJAX, and act upon the result in the `success` handler.

Comment: @meskobalazs So, I should explicitly set the value of the `<input type="text" />` by javascript after the processing of the ajax request has been completed. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Well, if you are not using data-binding JavaScript libraries, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @meskobalazs No, I'm not. Honestly, this is the first time I've heard about such libraries. Could you give an example?

Comment: They are quite complicated for such simple scenarios like this, but KnockoutJS, BackboneJS, EmberJS and AngularJS are all providing two-way data binding. There are others too, but I only know these (not too deeply, mind you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit your form with AJAX. E.g. using JQuery

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

and process the result updating necessary DOM element.

See e.g. [here](http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/) or [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)